# How to control irregular Image button click area in cocos2dx

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I want to use multiple irregular picture makes up a map, each picture is a button.Transparent part of the images will overwrite each other, how should I do to make their control areas does not overlap.

I use a lot of pictures makes up a large map.
And each piece of the map is irregular, but their control area is a rectangle. Because they all have transparent pixels.

I just want to make the hit area and their shape becomes the same.Some encountered a similar problem?

Comment: you might want to read this : http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/fast-pixelperfect-collision-detection-cocos2d-code-1of2/

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented one for the cocos2d-x v3.x:
https://github.com/yszheda/cocos2d-x-irregular-button

It works OK on cocos2d-x v3.2. Maybe you can have a try XD